# Задать рамки для изменения размера

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня скрипт рандомно должен менять модельку, и вот когда я начал писать код
Понял что переменная типа floаt может содержать только лишь 1 значание, в чем соль собственно.

мне нужно чтоб через юнити я мог в скрипте менять 2 публичные переменнные, которые и являются рамками (максимальный и минимальный размер).

Я теперь без понятия как их указать, и как это написать, ладно бы я просто мог написать там `Cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(Random.Range(1f, 1f, 1f));`, но нет.

Если говорить точнее, вот это вот так должно выглядеть :

```
Cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(Random.Range(МаксРазмер,МинРазмер));
```

ну или во всяком случае как-то похоже на это, в общем.
Я без малейшего понятия как сюда приплести публичную переменную...

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас объект квадратный (а обычно это так), то есть размер по x и y должен быть одинаков, то примерно так. Пусть класс с публичными переменными - MyClass, он висит на объекте MyObj, а переменные MaxScale, MinScale;

```
MyClass myClass = myObj.GetComponent<MyClass>();
float scale = Random.Range(myClass.minScale, myClass.maxScale);
Cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);
```

Если игра 2Д, то последним параметром можно указать 1.